# Raphael text element inside a jquery template

Tags: jquery, text, raphael, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I have a problem creating raphael js text elements inside a jquery template element

it appears, as raphael js graphics is created before the container is attached to the dom, the position of raphael text is shifted

this apply only to text elements. lines, circles and all the rest are fine

anyone had the same problem?
any solution other than not using jquery template?

Answer (score 0):

You should delay you Raphaël code until the DOM is fully loaded :

```
$(window).load(function(){
    //Put Raphaël code here.
});
```